# `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` returns false first time I query it

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm creating an iPhone app and want to ask the user for push notifications at a certain point in the app and that is when he turn a switch on.

The flow would be this: Start app->play a game->end game->custom pop-up with a switch appears and asks do you want to turn push notifications on?-> If yes then `registerForRemoteNotifications` is called (iOS 8) -> if no the user can go to settings (inside my app) and turn a switch on which should ask him again.

The problem is that when the user goes to settings (inside my app) to turn it on I don't know if `registerForRemoteNotifications` was called. 
If I check `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` it always returns no before the first `registerForRemoteNotifications` is called so that is not an option.

I could call `registerForRemoteNotifications` first but if the user disabled the app from notification center no callback is called so I can't present a pop-up saying you disabled the notifications.

So basically what I want is that the pop-up from Apple for push notifications to be at a certain point inside my app and also allow the user to manually turn on, off notifications inside my app. Also I would like when I show the settings screen to know if the user disabled the notifications from outside the app so he sees the notifications are disabled.

Is there any way to achieve this? Do I have to save local variables in NSUserDefaults to know if `registerForRemoteNotifications` was called?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings]` to show Apple's push notification permission pop-up.

If you want to check your app settings' notification status you can use this:

```
UIUserNotificationType currentType = [UIApplication currentUserNotificationSettings].types;
UIUserNotificationType required = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

if (currentType == UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {
    //show enable message
} else if (!(currentType & required)){
    //show enable UIUserNotificationTypeBadge or
    //UIUserNotificationTypeAlert message
}
```

Comment: I know about both usages but I want to first check and then in case I didn't register to call the register push notifications. The problem is that the current flow is the following: Check->If no, then why no? Because disabled from settings or because the user was never asked? I can't find anything that shows me if the user was asked or not.

Comment: I think you might have to store registerForRemoteNotifications call in NSUserDefaults, because I don't think the framework gives you the reason of "no".